# using a list from a function in a context in django celery

Tags: python, django, celery

i have a script (scrapt.py) that i am running frequently with celery beat. the script contains a list that stores what i scrape. how do i use this list in a context?
tasks.py

```
import time
from celery import shared_task, task
from .scrapt import scrape

@task
def scrape_dev_to():
    
    scrape()
    return
```

this scrapt.py contains the function

```
import os
os.chmod('./chromedriver', 0o755)
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def scrape():

    opt = Options()
    
    opt.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    opt.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    
    opt.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, 
    executable_path='./chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://www.ig.com/en/forex/markets-forex')


    timeout = 10

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH,
                "//div[@class='dynamic-table__cell']")
            )
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Struggling to get the page....Have faith in this buggy script!")
        
    data = []

    while not data:
        for elm in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=V2-F-BID]"):
            if elm.text and elm.text != '-': # Maybe check on contains digit
                data.append(elm.text)
        time.sleep(7)

        
    tet =[]
    while not tet:
        for em in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=OFR]"):
            if em.text and em.text != '-': # Maybe check on contains digit
                tet.append(em.text)
        time.sleep(7)
    print(data)
    return data
```

This is the views function, my attempt was to import the scrape function and for a weird reason, i felt i could use the data list in the context. i even tried to to  add a the function in it, but i got a positional argument error. i am getting everything messed up. i just want to continously display new data or tet list on my template.

```
def pricelist(request):
    from .scrapt import scrape
    
    scrape()


           
    context = {
        "price": 123,
        "mydata": data
    }

    return render(request, 'pricelis.html', context)
```

Comment: I would suggest writing Django command instead of writing separate script to be in the context of Django. Then you can run that command using manage.py or django-admin.py.

Comment: I don't see how that could solve the problem. Can you explain further.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Can you please post the stack trace to understand the exact issue?